# Do I need to check a child async/await function was successful in the parent?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

If I have a MongoDb update query, like the below - when it finishes and there is an error, the error will be passed to my parent function - that calls `updateQuery()`. In this case I know when the function has finished processing.

If the function is successful (i.e there are no errors) - do I just assume that it has finished processing successfully?

Or do I need to return something specific to the parent function to confirm this? (i.e return True, then check if its true)

```
async function updateQuery() {
  const db = await mongoUtil.getDb();

  return await db
    .collection("test")
    .updateOne(
      {
        _id: <id>,
      },
      {
        $set: {
          param: 'test'
        },
      }
    )
    .then((result) => {
      if (result.nModified !== 1) {
        throw new Error("Update Error");
      }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're using `async` `await`, there's no need to chain it with `.then`.

Store the result of `updateOne` in a variable and then check for the condition and `throw` an error.

Now, when you call `updateQuery` you will get an error if any otherwise the update operation was successful.

```
async function updateQuery() {
  const db = await mongoUtil.getDb();

  const res = await db
    .collection("test")
    .updateOne({ _id: "" }, { $set: { param: "test" } });

  if (res.nModified !== 1) {
    throw new Error("Update Error");
  }
}

updateQuery().catch(console.log);
```

Comment: @tbowden Please check if this solves your problem, do let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: Thanks Som - Really helpful - is there any big drawbacks of doing it the way I've written the function?

Comment: @tbowden Currently there's no drawback as such it's just unnecessary code. But suppose you were using `.find` and you were to return a document from the function then you couldn't have done that inside the `then` callback.

Comment: @tbowden I hope it's clear now, let me know if there's something that's still not clear.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! In the example you gave above regarding `find`, i need to `return res` to get the result to my parent function - right?

Comment: @tbowden Ya right! Consider accepting this as an answer if it was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `async` syntax, that means that the function will return a `Promise`. When you use `async` you can wrap logic inside `try/catch` block, and if any error occurs, it will be send to `catch` block. In both situations (success or error) you should return the value to the parent function. Of course, you can send an `error` to `Error Handler` instead of the parent function. You can refactor your code like this:

```
async function updateQuery() {
  try{
    const db = await mongoUtil.getDb();
    const result = await db.collection("test").updateOne(
      {  _id: <id> },
      {  $set: { param: 'test' } }
    );
    return {success: true, result};  
  } catch(error) {
    return {success: false}
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nenad - Would you say its best practice to return success/fail as your example shows? IMO I think I should do it, however I can't find many example. Cheers

Comment: There are a lot of different practices. I use this one. I am sending `success/fail` responses with descriptive messages and results to the parent function. After that you can handle the response in the parent function based on return value of the child function. For example, if error occurred, you can send error response to the end user with descriptive error message that you got from the child function. Also, if the result was success, you can send the data to the end user.

Comment: This is great Thanks! Once more thing, I've used the promises format in lots of places in my project. I assume if I do something like Som's answer below I can just add an `else {  return {success: true, result} }` for example to get a similar effect?

Comment: Yeah, you can use the Promises approach also. It is the same, but different syntax.